# Are there any unique rewards from Cucco Run endless mode?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

In Hyrule's Kakariko Village, there is a cucco-dodging minigame called Cucco Run. I've already earned the heart piece that you can get by beating Rooster mode, but I haven't completed Endless mode yet. The proprietress tells me that there's a reward for surpassing 100 seconds, but I don't particularly feel like trying over and over to beat it unless it's something that I can't earn any other way.

Are there any items that I can only obtain by beating Endless mode, or is there some other compelling reason to keep trying to beat it?

Comment: You can make Endless mode a lot easier by simply pausing with Start whenever you’re in danger. You can still see the arena behind the pause screen, so just look at where the birds are and the direction they are going and figure out an exit path, then choose Continue and immediately hold the Circle Pad in that direction. Keep your right thumb on Start at all times and press it if you get surprised. However, this makes the game take far longer than 999 seconds in real time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every 100 seconds you get 100 rupees.  Only the last one (999+) is different:

100 /100 Rupees

200 /200 Rupees

300 /300 Rupees

400 /400 Rupees

500 /500 Rupees

600 /600 Rupees

700 /700 Rupees

800 /800 Rupees

999 /3000 Rupees and a Giant Cucco

Comment: What does the giant cucco do?

Comment: @Zibbobz It's like the Cow in OoT, except instead of milk it restores one heart each time you talk to it. It sits next to the Cucco lady after you get it.

Comment: 999 is almost impossible. I just gave up.